# What does typing.cast do in Python?

Tags: python, types, casting

```
import typing
type(typing.cast(int, '11'))
```

still returns `<class 'str'>` instead of `int`. Then, what does `typing.cast` do here?

Comment: What it says it does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast

Answer (score 45):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) (emphasis mine):

> Cast a value to a type.
>
> **This returns the value unchanged.** To the type checker this signals that the return value has the designated type, but at runtime we intentionally don’t check anything (we want this to be as fast as possible).

The "casting" only takes place in the type-checking system, not at runtime.

Comment: To actually convert the string `"11"` to an int, use `int('11')` or `int('11', 2)` if you want to use a non-decimal base ( '11' in base 2 is the same as '3' in base 10).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! What changes are made if this doesn't change the actual value?

Comment: @Craig: [This part](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#casts) of PEP 484 may be helpful. `Casts differ from type comments (see the previous section). When using a type comment, the type checker should still verify that the inferred type is consistent with the stated type. When using a cast, the type checker should blindly believe the programmer. Also, casts can be used in expressions, while type comments only apply to assignments.`

Comment: @ZevChonoles that's odd. I'm almost certain I've had the type checker refuse a `cast` when I'm trying to cast to the wrong type

Comment: @joel `cast` will let you do anything, e.g. `result: int = cast(int, None); result += 1` which obviously fails at runtime.

Comment: If cast lets you do anything, and checks nothing, then what is the point of it? Isn't there a version of cast that at least checks whether the types are compatible in some way? (Even so little as checking whether one is a subclass)

Comment: @cowlinator The purpose is for static type checkers – see my answer. If you want something at runtime, you could `isinstance()` for example with the statement `assert isinstance(myvar, int)`

Comment: Yes, I understand that they are for static type checkers. My point is that static type checkers could check subclasses, since subclasses are statically defined.

Comment: one note for anyone like myself who thought `cast`ing wasn't working.  You must do:

`casted_thing = typing.cast(<type>, <actual_value>)`

in order for the type checker to use it right, pyright and mypy were giving me a headache. The outputted variable is the thing that _now_ ignores the type (for the type checker's purposes).  You can also do an inplace such as `for _ in typing.cast(<type>, <actual_value>): ...`

Answer (score 0):

There's context missing from the other answer that you need to understand before the answer to this question makes sense:

### What is static typing?

Python supports type hints, but they are ignored when you run the program. (Technically it is possible to inspect the type hints at runtime, but this is very rarely used.) For example, the following program will run without error even though `print_int` is being passed a `str` not an `int`:

```py
def print_int(x: int) -> None:
    print("The int is:", x)

print_int("seven")
```

Usually, in practice, if a function type hint is present then the function won't work with other types of classes (unlike the above `print_int()` which does actually work for non-`int` objects). But to find this out you still have to run the program, which is annoying because it could be that this function is rarely called, or the argument type is only wrong sometimes, or it takes a long time to run, etc.

However, it is possible to run a separate program, called a type checker, that will check that the type hints match up. The two commonly used ones are [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [pyright](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/). These will run over your codebase and check all annotated functions, classes and variables. For example, with the above program, mypy will say:

```
error: Argument of type "Literal['seven']" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "int" in function "print_int"
```

Notably, the type checkers do not run your program – they *just* check the types. This means they run quickly and detect type errors in all code paths. For example, they will detect the error in the following snippet, even though the code path with an error is unlikely at run time:

```
from random import randrange
y = randrange(1000000)
z = "seven" if y == 7 else y
print_int(z)
```

For this snippet, pyright will give the error:

```
error: Argument of type "int | Literal['seven']" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "int" in function "print_int"
```

### What is the use of `typing.cast`?

Now we can finally answer the original question. Consider the following variant of the example code:

```
y = randrange(1000000)
z = "seven" if y == 7 else y
if y != 7:
    print_int(z)
```

This code will only ever pass an `int` to `print_int` at runtime. However, the convoluted way this code is written is a bit too clever for the type checkers. All they know is that `z` is of type `int | str`, and it's being passed to something that needs an int, so they still give an error. So this is where we can help it out with `typing.cast`:

```
y = randrange(1000000)
z = "seven" if y == 7 else y
if y != 7:
    print_int(typing.cast(int, z))
```

As the docs and the other answer notes, this does not change what happens at runtime at all. However, it does silence the type checkers (if we ever run one) because it assures them that the argument being passed to `print_int()` really is an int, so no error is generated.

Beware that it is a blunt tool: by definition, it overrides type checking, so it's possible to use it when the types are not actually right. For example, this would pass type checkers with no error:

```
y = randrange(1000000)
z = "seven" if y == 7 else y
print_int(typing.cast(int, z))  # Oops
```