# Use string value for argument typed as Literal

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I use [kms.decrypt()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.20.1/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.decrypt) method from boto3 package.
For typing support I use the [boto3-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/) package.

The decrypt method has attribute `EncryptionAlgorithm`, which is typed as

```py
EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType = Literal["RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1", "RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256", "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"]
```

I parse the encryption algorithm via regular expression from input string so in my case the EncryptionAlgorithm value is `str`, not a Literal. Mypy complaint for it.

I do not want to disable type check for this line and the only solution I was found is the helper method which convert the str value to literal in this way:

```py
import boto3
from mypy_boto3_kms.literals import EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType

def getEncryptionAlgorithmLiteral(algorithm: str) -> EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType:
  result: EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType
  if algorithm == "RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1":
    result = "RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1"
  elif algorithm == "RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256":
    result = "RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256"
  elif algorithm == "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT":
    result = "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"
  else:
    raise Exception(f"Unexpected algorithm '{algorithm}'. It must be one of {EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType}")
  return result

def main(binaryEncData: bytes, keyId: str, algorithm: str):
  kms = boto3.client('kms')
  kmsResult = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=binaryEncData, 
                          KeyId=keyId,
                          EncryptionAlgorithm=getEncryptionAlgorithmLiteral(algorithm))
```

I wonder if there is some better way how to achieve the conversion in `getEncryptionAlgorithmLiteral()` method so I do not need to type all these values twice. Ideally I would like to use values directly from `EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType` type instead of typing them again to my code.

Comment: Wouldn't `if algorithm in ('RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1','RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256','SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT'):` / `return algorithm` do what you want?

Comment: Why do you need to type them twice? Just use `result = algorithm`. Or just end with `return algorithm`.

Comment: You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @TimRoberts From the functional point of view it will work, of course. But the type of te return value will be `str` - not `Literal` and mypy will complain about this. The same is valid for @Barmer suggestion.

Comment: Well, then throw it out.  If a tool forces you to use unnatural programming practices, then the tool sucks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to assure mypy that user input is in a set of literals](/q/67584236/90527)", "[Mypy can't infer the type of items from a list of Literals](/q/67367761/90527)"

Comment: @outis, yes, they provide the same solution as the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) to get the arguments passed in to `typing.Literal`. In this case, you'll need to combine it with [`typing.cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51457563/10237506) so you can signal to "mypy" that the string value that the function returns is an acceptable `Literal` value.

```py
from typing import cast
# Import below from `typing` in Python 3.8+
from typing_extensions import Literal, get_args


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType = Literal["RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1",
                                      "RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256",
                                      "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"]

_valid_algorithms = get_args(EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType)
print(_valid_algorithms)


def get_encryption_algorithm_literal(
        algorithm: str) -> EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType:

    if algorithm not in _valid_algorithms:
        valid_values = str(list(_valid_algorithms)).replace("'", "")
        raise Exception(f"Unexpected algorithm '{algorithm}'. "
                        f"It must be one of {valid_values}")

    # cast string to literal, so static type checkers such as 'mypy'
    # don't complain.
    return cast(EncryptionAlgorithmSpecType, algorithm)


def main():
    # noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
    string = 'RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256'

    my_algorithm = get_encryption_algorithm_literal(string)
    print(type(my_algorithm), my_algorithm)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
('RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1', 'RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256', 'SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT')
<class 'str'> RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256
```

Result for an invalid input like `'RSAES_OAEP_SHA_2567'`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    raise Exception(...)
Exception: Unexpected algorithm 'RSAES_OAEP_SHA_2567'. It must be one of [RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1, RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256, SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not solve the issue from question. I need to convert the `algorithm` string value to something, which can be used as an parameter of `kms.decrypt()` function and this parametr must be typed as Literal - otherwise mypy complains about this.

Comment: @eNca I updated my answer, but it looks like you'll need to use a `typing.cast` here to signal to the type checker that the string value in the return is in one of the Literal values. If you have a look at how it's implemented, the `cast` function is essentially just a no-op that returns the argument being passed in; yet type checkers can use it to understand that a value is actually of the specified type.